# HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 second - IEDriver - Selenium C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-iedriver

I have a Selenium automation suite up and running with chrome which works like a charm. I have integrated IEdriver within. After integrating I executed few of the test cases and getting problem with the execution on IE11. I observed that my test fails with the exception "HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds" . This behavior is random for every run and in continuing tests, pop up window is always logged out in application. Did anyone face similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe increasing the timeout?

```
InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"c:\pathtoie", options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing development and test execution on VM and whenever I lock my system, the script hangs on the VM. So doing execution on a VM from different VM will solve the problem.